# Grouping a SQL statement and extracting info via PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have a table that is structured with data like this:

```
TransactionID | saleID | productType | Price
1             | 1001   | subtotal    | 19.50
2             | 1001   | tax         | 3.11
3             | 1002   | subtotal    | 19.50
4             | 1002   | tax         | 3.11
```

I am trying to extract the value of the Price field, per SaleID that match numbers, and have it put into  PHP variables for subtotal & tax.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you add the wanted result as well? (Format same way as the existing table data.)

Comment: `per SaleID that match numbers` ... what does this mean?

Comment: `select saleID, SUM(Price) from some_table group by saleID` ?

Comment: the name of the table is `transactionTable`

Comment: What I would like as a result is:  a $sale array,   $sale[subtotal][price]  and $sale[tax][price]   based on matching saleID

Comment: bassxzero, I am not looking for the SUM, I just want to get the information into PHP and group it by the SaleID

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what your actual problem is. If you know how to use SQL from PHP, you certainly know how to read the results and you know how to add data to an array. So you can just read the table data sorted by saleID and fill an array in a loop.

Anyway, it may help you to get one record per saleID instead:

```
select saleid, st.price as subtotal_price, t.price as tax_price
from (select * from transactiontable where producttype = 'subtotal') st
join (select * from transactiontable where producttype = 'tax') t using (saleid);
```

This is standard SQL. If your DBMS does't support the `USING` clause, you'll have to switch to `ON` instead.

Here is your sample and the query result:

```
TransactionID | saleID | productType | Price
1             | 1001   | subtotal    | 19.50
2             | 1001   | tax         | 3.11
3             | 1002   | subtotal    | 19.50
4             | 1002   | tax         | 3.11
```

Result:

```
saleid | subtotal_price | tax_price
1001   | 19.50          | 3.11
1002   | 19.50          | 3.11
```

Comment: Yes I have the above data in a PHP array, but I'm not sure how to get it to group by the saleID.  So I'm getting all the rows, but not sure how to match the results on the saleID.

Comment: So you didn't know how to loop through your array to assemble subtotal and tax per saleID? Then my query should solve this, because you get both in one result row. Correct?

Comment: Hi Thorsten, This is not working.  It returns rows where the price is always 19.50, but I also need the tax for that sale.    The table is structured weird, making this a bit tricky to figure out.

Comment: I think the solution needs to be in PHP, but I'm not sure

Comment: Well, in your examples the price *is* 19.50 and the tax is 3.11. So these *are* the values that should be returned for salesid 1001 and 1002.

Comment: I think I'm going to have to do multiple queries and put them in different arrays.  Thanks for the help all.

Comment: Thorston the table has a price field, and the productType determines if it is 'subtotal' or 'tax'.

Comment: Yes. So my query selects the subtotals and the taxes and joins them per saleID. What else is it that you want? I've added the query result to my answer. If you need a different result, you should add it to your request.

Answer (score 0):

To group the data into a PHP array I would approach it as follows

```
//$db = mysqli connection
$sql = "SELECT * FROM transactionTable ORDER BY saleID";
$result = $db->query($sql);
$group = [];
while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){
    if( !isset($group[$row->saleID] ){
        $group[$row->saleID] = [];
    }
    $group[$row->saleID][] = [
        'transaction' => $row->transactionID,
        'productType' => $row->productType,
        'price' => $row->price
    ];
}

var_dump($group);
```

The resulting array `$group` will be very easy to work with. And you can construct it a bit differently depending on your use case.